# Momentum and Higgs Fields

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, higgs, classical-field-theory

A photon does not have mass thus it does not interact with the Higgs Field. However, it has momentum. How can this be represented in the Higgs Field as momentum is a property exhibited by particles with mass except for photons?

Comment: The Higgs was first observed through its decay to two photons. Even though this interaction is not in the standard model Lagrangian, it is induced by quantum fluctuations ("fermion loops" in QFT). Can you parse out your question in more specific detail?

Answer (score 4):

There are two separate confusions here.

1. Things do not need mass to have momentum. This is simply a fact of nature. Things don't even need to be particles to carry momentum. If photons / the electromagnetic field couldn't carry momentum then the electromagnetic force would never be able to change the momentum of charged objects, which it clearly does.

The formula $p = mv$ is not the definition of momentum. It tells you a relationship between the momentum of a slowly moving massive object and its speed, but different kinds of objects have different relationships. The momentum of an electromagnetic plane wave is $p \sim \vec{E}\times\vec{B}$, and the momentum of a photon is related to its wavelength by $p = 2\pi h/\lambda$.

2. Not all mass comes from interactions with the Higgs field, and interactions with the Higgs field don't necessarily cause mass.

As Cosmas Zachos pointed out in a comment, the Higgs field absolutely does interact with photons, just not in a way that gives the photon a mass.

Most of the mass of protons and other quark bound states has nothing to do with the Higgs field, and would occur even if there were no Higgs field. Neutrino masses may have very little to do with the Higgs field. In fact, there are theories (now disproven) that allow everything to have mass without a Higgs field or Higgs boson at all.

The Higgs field is the simplest theoretical solution to a problem: the way the weak interaction works seems at first glance to be incompatible with the weak bosons having mass or the leptons having mass. It is not the only theoretical solution to this problem, but it does appear to be the one Nature uses. However, the Higgs field is not the end-all-be-all of everything having to do with mass, so get that misconception out of your head and tell your friends.

Answer (score 1):

Relativistically, momentum is related to both energy and mass, by $E^2=m^2c^4+p^2c^2$. Photons certainly have energy, but not mass, so the momentum of a photon of energy $E$ will have magnitude $|p|=E/c$. The fact that photons (and any particle) has momentum is completely unrelated to the Higgs mechanism, and instead comes directly from relativity.